# How to integrate $f'(\ln x)/x$ given a table of values of $f$ and $f'$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My professor gave me this question without any description.

> 2. $$\int_1^e \frac{f'(\ln x)}{x}\,dx$$
>      where $f$ has the following data:
>      \begin{array}{r|lllll}
>    x& 0 & 1 &\frac{\pi}{2} & e & 3\\\hline
>    f(x) & 5 &7 & 8&10&11\\\hline
>    f'(x)& 2 & 4 &6 & 9&12
>    \end{array}

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE2vf.png)

I have no idea what I should get from this question. Can anyone understand it? Thank you!

Comment: Try a substitution such as $u=\ln(x)$.. You will eventually use the table to evaluate the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\ln(x)$. You get $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$. So integral becomes $\int f'(u) du$.

Now we need to figure out what the limits of integration are. When $x=1$, $u = \ln(1) = 0$, and when $x=e$, $u=\ln(e) = 1$. So the integral is now $\int_0^1 f'(u) du$. You should know how to go from here (Hint: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: oh! so we don't have to use all of nums from table just select what we need..right? that is confusing me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is very normal for questions in math classes to give you far more information than you need (or that is relevant).